# Conversion of Nginx to Apache Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I'm having to move nginx sites over to apache and I'm having an issue w/ mod rewrite rules. These are my nginx rewrite rules and I'm not... quite... nailing it as I've tried various iterations on my .htaccess file and it's not quite working for me. I'm also not having an easy time finding a 1:1 conversion on the net and regex has always confounded me.

```
 location / {
                index   index.php;
                try_files $uri /index.php?$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ ^/(.*\.php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param FWENV 'development';
        }
```

Primarily where I'm getting stuck is the

`location ~ ^/(.*\.php)$ {`

and how it interacts with

`try_files $uri /index.php?$uri&$args;`

inside of the .htaccess directives

Any help would be appreciated.

Where I left off was:

RewriteRule ~ /(.*.php) $1 [L,NC]

But I'm pretty sure I'm wayyyy off. I've been making slight variations of adding ^ and $ around the rule and some give me errors upon apache restart, others do not, none, however, give me a proper rewrite in the browser.

**UPDATE:**

I've started to use this particular rule because it does catch some of the issues but I believe my original NGINX rule incorporates it better. If anyone has a better idea, please, let me know.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|ttf|js)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&process=$3&object_id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)?$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&process=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2 [L]
```

So refining it a bit, now when I do the following, everything still works (as much as it did) but still doesnt work (urls like example.com/blah). I'm confounded as to why.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|ttf|js)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)?$ /index.php? [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the answer eventually and it was very close to the what I had for nginx (although I still don't understand it all that well).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|ttf|js)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```